# Mismatch of entities in the document during migrate:data

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I can see successfully migrate all the data except this warning is occuring "Mismatch of entities in the document" for some tables like, catalog_category_entity_text, catalog_category_product_index, catalog_product_entity_text, catalog_product_entity_varchar, url_rewrite.

I can see the M1 table has more column than M2 table. I can see in map.xml that those additional collumns are already ignored by tool. Still it is showing this issue.

How can i solve it? Becasue of this i am not able to see product names and descriptions etc.

Comment: I tried by deleting an additional column from catalog_product_entity_varchar in M1.  but warning still occurs